# Using Chrome command line args --window-workspace not working

Tags: macos, google-chrome, puppeteer, chromium

I'm trying to configure `puppeteer` to launch Chrome on a specific screen (or workspace) on macOS. I've found the `--window-workspace` CLI argument but it doesn't work. I tried every number from `0` to `10` (the number of workspaces I have on 3 screens), and the Chrome window shows up in the same workspace.

```bash
/Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome\ Canary --window-workspace=3
```

Is there a different way of identifying the workspace?

This is especially useful when working with multiple monitors and debugging `puppeteer` with headless mode turned off, having the ability to designate a screen where the window shows up would better the developer UX.

Comment: Any luck finding the answer to this? I'm a Windows user also looking to open Chrome to a specific screen...